# How do I get "redirect permanent" to work in Safari?

Tags: apache-2.2, ssl, https, httpd

I want to force https. All certificates, signed and ready, are working. In httpd.conf, I put:

```
redirect permanent / https://my.site.org
```

It seems Firefox and Chrome use https, but in Safari it just doesn't. If I click on a link with https in it, it works. But for the index.html, it doesn't want to.

Any ideas on why?!

**httpd.conf:**

```
 <VirtualHost *:80>
 ServerAdmin info@mysite.info
 DocumentRoot /var/www/html
 ServerName admin.mysite.info
 redirect permanent / https://admin.mysite.info
 #ServerAlias admin.mysite.info
 #ErrorLog logs/dummy-host.example.com-error_log
 #CustomLog logs/dummy-host.example.com-access_log common
</VirtualHost>
```

**ssl.conf**

```
<VirtualHost _default_:443>
DocumentRoot "/var/www/html"
ServerName admin.mysite.info:443

SSLEngine on
SSLCertificateFile /etc/httpd/ssl/certificate.crt
SSLCertificateKeyFile /etc/httpd/ssl/apache.key
SSLCertificateChainFile /etc/httpd/ssl/certificateCA.crt
```

Comment: What is the complete Apache configuration?

Comment: @TeroKilkanen See edited original post.